# Python or SQL Logistic Regression

Tags: python, sql, math, machine-learning, regression

Given time-series data, I want to find the best fitting logarithmic curve. What are good libraries for doing this in either Python or SQL?

Edit: Specifically, what I'm looking for is a library that can fit data resembling a sigmoid function, with upper and lower horizontal asymptotes.

Comment: Finding the best fitting logarithmic curve is not the same as logistic regression.  Do you have a library for linear regression ?

Comment: I see your point. I've used the standard linear regression functions in SQL (STDDEV,R2,SLOPE,etc) to find a best fitting line, so I thought the equivalent procedure using a logistic model would be called "logistic regression". I've found several sites that refer to regression to mean line-fitting, however, I've also found some sites using this term to actually mean classification. I'm not referring to classification. What would be the standard terminology for referring to line fitting using a logistic model?

Comment: what you are looking for may well be called 'logistic regression' but the fitted line will not be logarithmic but logistic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data were categorical, then you could use a logistic regression to fit the probabilities of belonging to a class (classification).

However, I understand you are trying to fit the data to a sigmoid curve, which means you just want to minimize the mean squared error of the fit.

I would redirect you to the [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/FittingData) function called `scipy.optimize.leastsq`: it is used to perform least squares fits.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using scipy.optimize.curve_fit, which seems to use a similar method.