# Weighted logistic regression in Python

Tags: python, regression

I'm looking for a good implementation for logistic regression (not regularized) in Python. I'm looking for a package that can also get weights for each vector. Can anyone suggest a good implementation / package?
Thanks!

Comment: pssible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754051/python-or-sql-logistic-regression

Comment: Nothing relevant in this post, I've also tried using scipy, but couldn't find any use of weights...

Answer (score 27):

I notice that this question is quite old now but hopefully this can help someone. With sklearn, you can use the SGDClassifier class to create a logistic regression model by simply passing in 'log' as the loss:

```
sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier(loss='log', ...).
```

This class implements weighted samples in the `fit()` function:

```
classifier.fit(X, Y, sample_weight=weights)
```

where weights is a an array containing the sample weights that must be (obviously) the same length as the number of data points in X.

See http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html for full documentation.

Comment: supported by Olivier Grisel https://twitter.com/ogrisel/status/476367379413610497

Comment: This uses one-vs-rest for multiclass problems and doesn't look like it supports the `multi_class='multinomial'` option in `LogisticRegression`

Answer (score 7):

The “balanced” mode uses the values of y to automatically adjust weights inversely proportional to class frequencies in the input data as n_samples / (n_classes * np.bincount(y))

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

model = LogisticRegression(class_weight='balanced')

model = model.fit(X, y)
```

**EDIT**

Sample Weights can be added in the fit method. You just have to pass an array of n_samples. Check out documentation -

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.fit

Hope this does it...

Comment: This refer to class imbalance, but what if we want to use separate weight for each sample?

Comment: Good question @mrgloom ! You can specify the weights by supplying a dict of weights instead of "balanced". Weights associated with classes in the form {class_label: weight}. If not given, all classes are supposed to have weight one.

Comment: I need separate weight for each sample, not for each class.

Comment: I dont think that comes off the shelf. You may have to use your own version of cost function and gradient descent update to do that.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you want is `statsmodels`. It has great support for GLM and other linear methods. If you're coming from R, you'll find the syntax very familiar.

[statsmodels weighted regression](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.WLS.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.WLS)

[getting started w/ statsmodels](http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/logistic-regression-and-python.html)

Comment: Will this statsmodels solution also provide the p-values for each dependent variable?

Comment: Seems to only have weighted linear regression, not logistic. "w is not yet supported (i.e. w=1), in the future it might be var_weights"

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [scikits.learn logistic regression implementation](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logisitic-regression)

Comment: `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression` is a class, his `fit` method let you defined weight.

Comment: @ohe how? I have found the `fit` method, but it only accepts parameters for labels and features. Not weights.

Comment: @KentMuntheCaspersen my answer is quiet old! At this time the `fit` method took a `class_weight` parameter. It is now located in th `__init__`. It might be what you're watching for.

Comment: @ohe That explains a lot. Thanks for coming back 4 years later. I think the question is about weighted instances for training, and not just class weights. At least, that is what I was searching for.

Answer (score -5):

Do you know Numpy? If no, take a look also to Scipy and matplotlib.

Comment: Scipy nor Numpy dot have any logistic regression implementation (or I couldn't find any...). matplotlib is mostly used for graphs, drawings, etc...

Comment: Thanks! I saw it, however it implements L2 regularized logistic regression (and not regular logistic regression), and in addition it didin't implement weights...